# How can I redirect a user to a www domain in PHP without the http?

Tags: php, http, redirect, https, header

I have a website (let's call it `www.mywebsite.com`) that allows users to enter a URL that other users on my website can be redirected to. If a user types in a full URL like so `https://www.google.com` then all is well because my `header()` function will redirect to exactly that.

However when a user enters in `www.google.com` or even `google.com` then the `header()` function will attempt to redirect to this `https://www.mywebsite.com/www.google.com`.

Remember, I can't fully format the user's URL myself because the program doesn't know whether the website is `https://` or `http://` and if you get this wrong the user can end up at a non existent page.

What I need is a method of telling PHP to just go to the URL specified without relativity to my website almost like the a user had typed it in the URL bar themselves.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only redirect to the `http://` if you don't know the protocol because it is REALLY the responsibility of the receiving website to have a redirect setup form HTTP to HTTPS.

Therefore if the user doesn't specify a protocol, you simply add the non-secure http protocol and it *should* get redirected to the correct page.

You *should not* be inserting `www` at all if the user hasn't put that in.

Notwithstanding all this, you could always perform a check yourself in your own code to see which protocols exist at the other end, but you should probably simple enforce the user supply it in the first place

Comment: I agree. It seems the function I am looking for simply doesn't exist. This was going to be my last resort but from what I can tell it's the only option. When the user enters the URL I will have to test if it starts with `http://` or `https://` and if it doesn't, ask them to copy and paste "the full url" from the address bar. Thanks.

Comment: most input fields allow data validation, just ensure it starts with `http[s]://`. I'm no regex guru, but a quick check on http://regex101.com confirms this should work for what you're after: `http[s]?\:\/\/`. There's no need for any further explaining, especially if you have placeholder text that has the http:// for them, but there's nothing to stop you from adding a note above or below it reminding them to include the protocol.